# How do I copy the TestNG output folder to some other folder?

Tags: copy, testng

I do have the code to do it, but when do I do it? It seems like when I do it AfterSuite I am copying the previous test-output files. I also created a custom listener but that didn't solve the problem since the report is created at the very end.

If this is not possible, is it then possible to programmatically change the output directory?

Comment: how are y invoking your tests?

Comment: I am using Eclipse with the TestNG plugin. I invoke the tests by right clicking on the xml file and running as a TestNG suite.

Comment: You can change the dir then from Project->Properties->Testng->output dir

Comment: But not programmatically? It's not always practical to use it that way.

Comment: If you run using commandline args, it is configurable from there.  If there are specific reports that you are generating implementing IReporter you can put in whichever dir you like, but default reports can only be configured from there or throu cla

Comment: The other question of moving all, you can have a reporter which moves the file, but since the order of reporters is not gauranteed, you can't gaurantee your reporter runs last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be if you run testng programatically.  You get control to set the output directory.

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setOutputDirectory("My dir");
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestClass1.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
```

The other question of moving all default reports, you can have a reporter which moves the file, but since the order of reporters is not gauranteed, you can't guarantee that your reporter runs last.